# In a log like this: 21-03-2020 07:09 [LOG] ralex /home/ralei/secret ACCESS_WRITE_OK How can i see if the user is the same in both path and log?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, logs

So I have a fie of logs like this:

```
20-03-2020 10:01 [LOG] davis /home/davis/fis1 ACCESS_WRITE_OK
20-03-2020 11:11 [LOG] davis /home/davis/Pictures/cat.png ACCESS_READ_OK
20-03-2020 12:22 [LOG] root /home/davis/hello ACCESS_READ_OK
20-03-2020 21:10 [ERROR] davis /root/secret.txt ACCESS_READ_DENY
20-03-2020 23:11 [LOG] davis /home/davis/secret ACCESS_READ_OK
20-03-2020 23:22 [ERROR] ralex /home/davis/secret ACCESS_WRITE_DENY
21-03-2020 06:00 [LOG] root /bin/bash ACCESS_READ_OK
21-03-2020 07:09 [LOG] ralex /home/ralex/secret ACCESS_WRITE_OK
21-03-2020 08:22 [ERROR] ralex /dev/sda1 ACCESS_READ_DENY
21-03-2020 14:12 [LOG] root /home/davis/.hidden/secret_root ACCESS_WRITE_OK
22-03-2020 07:09 [LOG] root /dev/sda ACCESS_READ_OK
```

And I need to extract only those logs where the user name is the same both in the path and the username column. After that i need to replace the absolute path with ~
And my file with logs shoul look like this:

```
20-03-2020 10:01 [LOG] davis ~/fis1 ACCESS_WRITE_OK
20-03-2020 11:11 [LOG] davis ~/Pictures/cat.png ACCESS_READ_OK
20-03-2020 12:22 [LOG] root /home/davis/hello ACCESS_READ_OK
20-03-2020 21:10 [ERROR] davis /root/secret.txt ACCESS_READ_DENY
20-03-2020 23:11 [LOG] davis ~/secret ACCESS_READ_OK
20-03-2020 23:22 [ERROR] ralex /home/davis/secret ACCESS_WRITE_DENY
21-03-2020 06:00 [LOG] root /bin/bash ACCESS_READ_OK
21-03-2020 07:09 [LOG] ralex ~/secret ACCESS_WRITE_OK
21-03-2020 08:22 [ERROR] ralex /dev/sda1 ACCESS_READ_DENY
21-03-2020 14:12 [LOG] root /home/davis/.hidden/secret_root ACCESS_WRITE_OK
22-03-2020 07:09 [LOG] root /dev/sda ACCESS_READ_OK
```

Can you help me with this problem?
Thanks! :)

Comment: This looks like a typical homework problem. What have you tried already? What part are you stuck on? We won't do your homework for you, but we can help you understand.

Comment: I can't do the matching between the username and the name in the path. I think that is my biggest problem. I tried "grep" and "sed" but I have some issues.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
sed "s/\<\([a-z]\{1,\}\)\>.*\<\1\>/\1 ~/g" FILENAME
```

---

That is the code for what I needed. It searches for lines where the username is found twice and it replaces the matching words with the first group (the username) and ~ for the /home/username/ path.
Not sure if its the best way to do it but id does the job :))

Comment: The "best" way is the way that you understand, can maintain, and can explain to others.  In real life, this is a good solution. Well done!